# Suggestions on for loop logic

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, servicenow

I'm working in ServiceNow and am seeking some guidance on a for loop.  This is a snippet of out of the box code for one of their widgets:

```
data.f = $sp.getForm(data.table, data.sys_id, data.query, data.view);
```

This produces a JSON object that looks something like this:

```
 "_sections": [{
     "_bootstrap_cells": 6,
        "_count": 2,
        "visible": true,
        "columns": [{
            "fields": [{
                "name": "type_of_account",
                "type": "field"
            }, {
                "name": "routing_transit_number",
                "type": "field"
            }]
        }, {
            "fields": [{
                "name": "type_of_payment",
                "type": "field"
            }, {
                "name": "check_digit",
                "type": "field"
            }]
        }],
        "caption": "Direct Deposit",
        "id": "b456b9d2137ac340177c36328144b0ef",
        "scope_name": "x_dnf"
    }, {
        "_bootstrap_cells": 12,
        "_count": 1,
        "visible": true,
        "columns": [{
            "fields": [{
                "name": "account_number",
                "type": "field"
            }, {
                "name": "account_title",
                "type": "field"
            }, {
                "name": "financial_institution_name",
                "type": "field"
            }]
        }],
        "caption": "",
        "id": "",
        "scope_name": "x_dnf"
    }
}]
```

In the above example, there's a section that has a caption and one that doesn't.  I want to loop through _sections and for those that do NOT have a caption, I want all of their fields to appear on the previous section that does have a caption.  In this particular example, the previous section happens to have a caption, but there could be a situation where there are multiple sections in a row that do NOT have a caption.  In that case, I want all of those sections without a caption to be pushed into the closest previous section that does.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

```
for (var s in data.f._sections) {
        var sc = data.f._sections[s];
        var sc_col = sc.columns;
        if (sc.caption == '') {
            for(var a=0; a<sc_col.fields.length; a++) {
                //push fields to closest previous section that has a caption
            }
        }
    }
```

**Additional Info**

Currently, the above code produces two separate tabs because I have a ng-repeat on _sections.  One of them has the caption 'Direct Deposit' and the other one has no caption at all:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVEzk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryy9W.png)

In the back-end, they are actually in one tab:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZvjr.png)

The only reason why they appear as two separate sections is because the first four questions are two columns and the remaining three questions are a single column.

My html to produce the tabs looks like this:

```
 <md-tab ng-repeat="container in containers" label="{{container.captionDisplay || container.caption}}">
```

My thought is to take those sections that do not have captions (because they're not really separate sections/tabs) and just append them to the closest previous tab that has a caption.

Comment: suggestion: you could keep track of the closest/previous section without having to reloop

Comment: hi @maioman, thanks!  can you explain how i could do that?

Comment: What if the first one has no caption?

Comment: @ScottSauyet, I've thought about that, but I don't think that scenario will actually occur in ServiceNow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not quite clear what you mean by `fields` here.  Is it the properties of the `column` sub-object?  If so, one possibility is to use `reduce` with an accumulator that has both the running tally of the possibly altered items and a reference to the most recent one that has a non-empty `caption`.  The code might look something like this:

```js
const data = [{"_bootstrap_cells": 6, "_count": 2, "caption": "Direct Deposit", "columns": [{"fields": [{"name": "type_of_account", "type": "field"}, {"name": "routing_transit_number", "type": "field"}]}, {"fields": [{"name": "type_of_payment", "type": "field"}, {"name": "check_digit", "type": "field"}]}], "id": "b456b9d2137ac340177c36328144b0ef", "scope_name": "x_dnf", "visible": true}, {"_bootstrap_cells": 12, "_count": 1, "caption": "", "columns": [{"fields": [{"name": "account_number", "type": "field"}, {"name": "account_title", "type": "field"}, {"name": "financial_institution_name", "type": "field"}]}], "id": "", "scope_name": "x_dnf", "visible": true}]

const transform = (data) => data.reduce(({lastCaptioned, all}, curr) => {
  if (curr.caption) {
    return {lastCaptioned: curr, all: all.concat(curr)}
  } else {
    lastCaptioned.columns = lastCaptioned.columns.concat(curr.columns)
    delete curr.columns;                            // Line A
    return {lastCaptioned, all: all.concat(curr)}   // line B
  }
}, {all: []}).all

console.log(transform(data))
```

If you didn't want to delete those fields from the caption-free elements, then just remove "Line A".

If you didn't want to even include the caption-free elements, then change "Line B" to read something more like

```
    return {lastCaptioned, all}
```

This would probably fail if the first element does not have a caption.  It could be fixed to deal with that, but I don't know the expected behavior, and it would likely lead to uglier code.

Comment: hey @scott_sauyet, thanks for this!  I may be thinking about this way too simplistically, but basically what I want is if there's a section that does not have a caption, to concat that entire section into the previous one.

Comment: What do you mean by `concat` here?  The sections are objects.  If you tried to concat the second one above onto the first one, whose `_bootstrap_cells`, `_count`, `id`, `visibility`, etc would end up on the new object?

Comment: hm, this conversation is making me rethink how to approach this.  I would actually want to keep both _bootstrap_cells, _count, etc because  the first one could be just a single column of fields, while the second one could have two columns of fields.  I want the two sections to be combined into one so they can appear under one tab in the front-end, but I still want each sections formatting to remain the way they are, if that makes sense.  Let me know if this makes any sense at all haha.  Thanks!

Comment: I really can't tell what you're looking for.  Sample output would really help.  You should be able to edit your question to add some.

Comment: thanks @scott_sauyet, I've posted some additional information, let me know if I'm making any sense.  Thanks for your guidance!

Comment: I'm afraid those updates miss the point.  I'm afraid I'm not particularly interested in your business problem, only in a possibly interesting technical one.  So... given the input you have above, what would you like the output to be?  Perhaps together we can come up with a function that would generate it.